# Reusing previous session asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, session, cookies

I am running some security checks on an applicationI have built using ASP.net MVC 4.

I am currently using a web debugger to compose unathorize posts during testing.

My application enforces a policy where data can only be modified by the user that added it.

I use methods similar to the follwing the check the current user Id

```
  if (item.AddedByUser != WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedException();
            }
```

However, when I tried duplicating a previous succesfull POST (using an older 'ASP.NET_SessionId') I found that the **WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId** method returned the userid of the user that was active during the previous session, rather than the userId of the currently active user.

This looks like a potential security hole to me.

Does anyone know how this happens?

**EDIT**

I am calling the Sessioon.Abandon() method and clearing the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie as part of my LogOff method as follows

```
    public virtual ActionResult LogOff()
    {


        WebSecurity.Logout();

        Session.Abandon();

        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH", ""));
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("__RequestVerificationToken", ""));

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


    }
```

However, the session still appears to be 'resusable' if a previous sessionid is passed as part of the POST

Comment: Was the previous Session active less than 20 minutes earlier? Maybe you could checkout `Session.Abandon` to kill off the session? [SessionID](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899918)

Comment: Hi LakshmiNarayanan, the session was active less than 20 minutes ago, but the user logged off and I did call Session.Abandon() in my LogOff() method.

Comment: I suppose the sessionIDs are being persisted in cookies, inspite of abandoing the session. You could consider rewriting the SessionID cookie after the Session.Abandon() is called, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716298/sessionid-is-still-the-same-after-session-abandon-call).

Comment: I appear to be already clearing the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie in my logoff method.  My edit above shows my logoff method