# Why not to reuse "ASP.NET_SessionId"?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, sessionid

I am new to asp.net and I don't understand why not to reuse the "ASP.NET_SessionId"?

From my understanding, every time a user requests a page from the server, the IIS creates for him an "ASP.NET_SessionId" and puts it in a cookie in the user browser.

I read about it here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918
And couldn't figure out why I should delete this cookie for a user after he logout.

It says:

> Sometimes, you may not want to reuse the session ID. If you do and if
> you understand the ramifications of not reusing the session ID, use
> the following code example to abandon a session and to clear the
> session ID cookie:
>
> Session.Abandon();
>
> Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));

Could you explain me what are the advantages of deleting this cookie and the disadvantages of reusing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't delete it and you are using http then it's a security risk

e.g.

1. Go to www.dodgyhacker.com, they have an invisible iframe which contains the login page for www.yoursite.com. They can see the cookie and send it to a remote server
2. Now navigate to www.yoursite.com, the cookie isn't changed and you log on
3. The dodgy hacker can now use your session cookie and get full access to the system

In reality there are others ways of protecting against this and I'm not a hacker so this may be slightly wrong but those are the essential steps

Comment: I don't think that by having my session cookie a hacker gets a full access to my information over the system...

Comment: It's called Session Hijacking. This covers it

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack

Comment: Also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/859579/Hack-proof-your-asp-net-applications-from-Session

Comment: I read the articles in both links and I don't get it.
Let's say I am logged in with session id  = 'X' and you go to same web site and have my session id, how does it help you? you need other details such as my username, my id for the website and so on.. I get the ASP.NET_SessionID before I am logging in.

Comment: Bear in mind we are talking generally here, your website may not have this problem, but... Once you are passed the log on page how does the server know that you are you? There's a good chance it does because it checks the session/authentication/other cookie. If someone else has these then as far as the system is concerned they are you.